# How to change text in UITextView and UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to edit my `UITextView` and when I make these changes I need them to reflect that in my `UITextFields`.  Currently i can use the code below to move whatever text i write into the first `UITextField` is there a simple way to move each line to a separate `UITextField`?

Like the image, except the 1, 2 and 3 going to a different `UITextField`.

```
-(IBAction)print:(id)sender {

NSString *texto = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[myTextField text],[myTextView text]];
[myTextField setText:texto];
[myTextView setText:@""];
[myTextView resignFirstResponder];

}
```

[image: Like this]

Really, I need to figure this out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, how would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your view controller conform to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol.

Next, set the `delegate` property of your text view to your view controller.

Then, implement `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView`, along these lines:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // Set the text for your text fields.
    //
    // (I'm assuming your code for determining the text to put in the
    // text fields works as you intend, so I'm just copying it here.)

    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [textView layoutManager];
    unsigned numberOfLines, index, numberOfGlyphs = [layoutManager numberOfGlyphs];
    NSRange lineRange;

    for (numberOfLines = 0, index = 0; index < numberOfGlyphs; numberOfLines++)
    {
        (void) [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:index
                                               effectiveRange:&lineRange];

        index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
        NSString *lineText = [textView.text substringWithRange:lineRange];
        [yourArray addObject:lineText];
    }

    textField1.text=yourArray[0];
    textField2.text=yourArray[1];
    textField3.text=yourArray[2];
    textField4.text=yourArray[3];
    textField5.text=yourArray[4];
    textField6.text=yourArray[5];
    textField7.text=yourArray[6]; 
}
```

Comment: Why not use the `textViewDidChange:` delegate method instead of `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:`? It's a much better choice in this case.

Comment: Though that still doesnt do a live update when i change text in the textview

Comment: i put in text into the textview and when the app loads it does show the text but the problem is that when the app runs i want to amend text then and have it show in the correct textfield.

Comment: Is the text in the text view being changed programmatically, or by typing into it with the keyboard? `textViewDidChange:` is called in response to the user typing into the text view. It isn't called in response to programmatic changes to the text. If you are changing the text programmatically, can't you just put your text field update code in a function, and call that function whenever you also update your text view?

Comment: how can I assign a property value in case of array of objects?  e.g. I want to assign 'name' property from my object from selected index to a text field..